# Three JS - Orbit controls on mobile/touch device

Tags: android, typescript, three.js, touch

Another probably-stupid question, but I have a scene that uses orbit controls to rotate the camera around, and it's all working fine (for the most part), but when testing for mobile/touch devices I run into an issue.

Basically, I have some objects floating around, and when you click one, you move the camera across to it and sit behind it, click the object again and you move the camera down right on top of it (filling most the screen), and then double-click and you come back out to sitting behind it again (ready to click another) to produce a sort of a focus/unfocus effect.

When you've clicked an object twice and it's filling the screen, I've enabled orbit controls and set the target to the position of the object, so you can rotate around the object in close-up, when you double-click to come back away from the object, orbit controls are disabled and the target is reset.

It all works fine on desktop, but when I test touch devices (in chrome dev tools and on device) the canvas seems to cease registering my mouse event listeners when orbit controls are enabled, so I can't double-click to come out.

I assume this is something to do with the orbit controls' own event listeners, waiting for touch start/move/end to do it's own thing, but I thought my listeners would still fire off, as it does in desktop?

Is there something I'm missing? I'm not sure if you need a code snippet/example as it functions totally as expected in desktop, so I'm hoping it's not my code in particular, more a behaviour of the library in regards to transitioning between device types.

I apologise if this is a duplicate question or something, but I couldn't find anything online to help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you need to add some event listeners for the touch events too in order to support mobile.  Orbit controls does this.  See line 913 at https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js

Comment: One thing to watch out for when handling touch events on Android is that a touchmove can be sent in between a touchstart and touchend, even for a simple tap.  Whereas on iOS there is no touchmove event unless you really move your finger.

Comment: Well, you were right in that I needed to add listeners for the touch events, but only because someone else had put `event.preventDefault()` in the mouse handler, thus when chrome automatically reconfigured my mouse event to a touch event, it was actually preventing that touch event from emulating the mouse events like it normally does, and therefore _because_ I hadn't added touch listeners, it wasn't doing anything for that either. So you were right, but also removing `preventDefault()` would've sorted it too, thanks man

Comment: this is not a stupid question... i am still not figure it out why my object is not touchable from android chrome browser